# Analytic continuation of $L$-functions of base changed elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, l-functions

Suppose that $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbf{Q}$. Let $K$ be a number field and let $L(E/K, s)$ be the Hasse-Weil $L$-function of $E$ base-changed to $K$. The modularity theorem tells us that $L(E/\mathbf{Q},s)$ has an analytic continuation to the entire complex plane. My question is: does the base-changed $L$-function $L(E/K, s)$ also have an analytic continuation to the entire complex plane?

Comment: Only in special cases. For instance, abelian extensions are ok as one can twist the modular form by any Dirichlet character and still get a modular form whose $L$-function has analytic continuation.

Comment: I was told that if $K$ is contained in a solvable extension then by base change theorem in the theory of automorphic forms, the base changed $L$-function has meromorphic continuation.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is *expected* to be true for any $K$, but it is only known in special cases. I'll leave it to an actual expert to tell us the current state of knowledge about which ones those are.

Comment: Does the standard argument using Brauer induction allow one to prove anything about the non-abelian case?

Comment: Brauer induction + potential modularity theorems give you meromorphy, not holomorphy, of the L-function, which is why meromorphic continuation is known in much greater generality (any totally real or CM field, and $E$ doesn't have to be a base-change from $\mathbb{Q}$ but can be any elliptic curve over $K$).